# How to get the length of a value from user input?

Tags: python

I'm working on an assignment:

My input is supposed to be a name, it could be anything.
The output is supposed to be the length of the name.

e.g.

Currently, I have:

```
print(input("What is your name? ")

print(len(input)
```

But the second half isn't correct.

Comment: You missed a `)` after both the `print` calls

Comment: When you run that code, you should have received an error message pointing you to the line where there is a syntax error. Also, please describe properly what you mean by "*isn't correct*".

Answer (score 2):

I think I located the problems in your code. This is what it should look like:

```
n = input("What is your name? ")

print((len(n))
```

I tested and switched things up a bit by adding a variable called "n" and giving it the input value. Then I wrote a changed into string version of the len of n... If that makes sense.

I put three brackets in the second line because the first one is for the print statement, the second one len, and the last one for the int.
Don't worry too much as it was an honest mistake! :)

PS. This is the better version of the code:

```
n = input("What is your name? ")

print("Your name has "+len(n)+" letters")
```

Comment: why would a name be an integer?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry about that. I changed my answer. If I were to do something like this: 'print("Your name has "+len(n)+" letters")' Then I would get an error that says cannot concatenate int to str. so I would have to change the value of len(n) to a string.

Comment: `str()` is redundant since `print()` automatically converts its arguments to `str`. So the first one should be `print(len(n))` and second `print("Your name has", len(n), "letters")`.

Comment: *"changed into integer version of the len"* -- A len already is an integer. I think you forgot to change this while making an edit.

Comment: @wjandrea If you do it like this: 'print("Your name has" + len(n) + "letters")', you get an error. However, if you do it like this: 'print("Your name has", len(n), "letters")', you don't get one. I think that was the misunderstanding between us. My way of doing it was probably less efficient so sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to DO something with the value, then you have to store it in a variable:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
print(name)
print(len(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, your one line code can done in this way:

`print(len(input("what is your name ?")))`